# What's the benefit of using multiple producers and consumers in the producer/consumer pattern for sorting strings in java?

Tags: java, multithreading, producer-consumer

We learned producer/consumer pattern during the class but only with the example of one producer and one consumer. In our homework, we are asked to do the following:

> Write a program that generates random strings, then sorts them
>   alphabetically using the producer/consumer pattern.  Create 1000
>   strings and use a bounded queue of size 100. Use 100 producers and 10
>   consumers.

Can anyone explain to me the benefit of implementing multiple producers and consumers instead of single producer and consumer in this situation? I assume multiple producers can generate multiple random strings, but what are multiple consumers designed for? To remove strings quicker from the queue and then put them to another array to sort?

Thank you.

Comment: I answered the question in theory on why use multiple consumers vs producers, but I don't quite see how you can benefit sorting with this pattern

Comment: @JohnVint Thank you still for your post. What role does consumer play in this situation? Taking out one string at a time from the queue, then putting the array in an array to sort? Or do you think the consumer just sort the strings in the queue every time there's a string added to the queue?

Comment: I suggest that you talk or email with your teacher.

Comment: @dead_programmer, I am honestly not sure. There are a number of parallel/concurrent sorting algorithms but none of them ever interact in a consumer/producer context.

Comment: @NomadMaker true that, I sent an email already and I will update this post later if I get a reply from my professor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the professor's reply, I think the assignment is asking us to sort each string alphabetically, like: `"aagpqhtpqht" -> "aaghhppqqtt"`, instead of what I understood as `"puatn", "qupango", "agnqotu", "bowtn" -> "agnqotu", "bowtn", "puatn", "qupango"`.

So I assume consumer's role is to take one string at a time from the queue, then sort THE string.

There's no benefit of using multiple consumers here for sorting strings alphabetically in this situation. It's supposed to be a practice for implementing producer/consumer pattern using multiple producers and consumers.